$P,Q \in CP^1$, |P|=|Q|=4. $\exists \phi s.t. \phi(P) = Q \iff f(s) = f(t)$, with $f(x) = \frac{(x^2-x+1)^3}{x^2(x-1)^2} $, s and p the cross-ratios
I am solving the following question: $\mathcal{P}$ = $\left\{P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4\right\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}P^1, \mathcal{Q} = \{ Q_1, Q_2, Q_3, Q_4\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}P^1$. Prove that there exists a projective transformation $\phi$, such that $\phi(\mathcal{P}) = \mathcal{Q} \iff \frac{(s^2-s+1)^3}{s^2(s-1)^2} = \frac{(p^2-p+1)^3}{p^2(p-1)^2}$, with $s = (P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4)$ and $p = (Q_1, Q_2, Q_3, Q_4)$ the cross-ratios. I have noticed that a projective transformation keeps the cross-ratio, and $(Q_1, Q_2, Q_4, Q_3) = 1/p, (Q_1, Q_3, Q_2, Q_4) = 1-p, (Q_1, Q_3, Q_4, Q_2) = 1/(1-p), (Q_1, Q_4, Q_2, Q_3) = 1-1/p, (Q_1, Q_4, Q_3, Q_2) = p/p-1$... Do I hace to write out all the 24 possibilities or how can I efficiently proceed. I now did (t-p)(t-(1-p))(t-(1-1/p))... = 0

You can use Möbius transformations to map any three of the points in each quadruple to $0, 1, \infty$. The fourth point will then be mapped to the cross-ratio $s$ of the four points. As you noted, reordering the quadruples transforms the cross-ratio. The rational map $\frac{(s^2-s+1)^3}{s^2(s-1)^2}$ is a polynomial that is invariant under these transformations; see here for more details.
